# null values after csv import

Tags: mysql

Consider a table to store SSN and DOB.

```
CREATE TABLE fbi
(
     ssn BIGINT, 
     dob DATE
)
```

Data was loaded into the table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE C:\test.csv
INTO TABLE fbi
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';


SELECT * FROM fbi;
```

It is showing null values for DOB. I don't understand the error.

```
"ssn","dob"
  5,"1952-11-15"
  6,"1973-12-23"
 6,"1951-12-23"
 1,"1962-03-21"
```

Comment: Please post some of the sample data in your CSV (but please censor the the ssn field first!!!)

Comment: can you post your test.csv file?

Comment: 1952-11-16- dob is in this mannner

Comment: @sphipls: Do you have that trailing dash after the day or is that a typo in your comment? The dash should not be there and would definitely cause a problem.

Comment: @Asaph, what are you referring to?

Comment: it's probably the quotes around the dates

Comment: @shilps: I've updated my answer with a `LOAD DATA INFILE` command that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely has to do with the date formatting in your csv file. MySQL likes dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. e.g. `2010-10-09`. You might be able to get more information by issuing the following command in the MySQL command console immediately after your import:

```
show warnings;
```

UPDATE:

I see that your date field is quoted. If you have a quoted date, you'll need to tell MySQL that by adding `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` to your import command (see MySQL manual for [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)). Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE C:\test.csv
INTO TABLE fbi
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

BTW: I hope those SSN's you've posted are fake or mangled in some unrecoverable way.

Comment: plz see the edited part of the question...so I have to do that now?

Comment: @shilps: It'll still be in the revision history of the question unfortunately. I'll flag this question for review by an admin.

Comment: well, I got the data from the HW that I got from my school.I dont think, there is any problem.

Comment: Oh, so those were *not* real social security numbers?

Comment: Ok, that's good. Unfortunately, I already flagged this question for moderator review.